# Recognize and Select Name in JComboBox with Space

Tags: java, database, sqlite

First I have table Appointment_Table with columns Appointment_ID,Doc_ID,Dep_Id,SchedDate,Patient_ID and Patient_Table with Patient_ID,FName,MI,LName, and so on.... and Doctor_Table with Doc_ID,FName,MI,LName and so on... so that I created a frame [Add Appointments frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IN9j8.jpg) with 3 JComboBox first is Department Name and it contains of course the Deparment Name and then the Doctor Names inside it contains FName,Mi,LName and same for the Patient Name.

So that I insert all departments name in JCombobox that only have a doctor

```
public void ViewDepartmentName(){
   try{
       String sql = "Select DISTINCT Department_Name from Department_Table\n" +
                    "inner join User_Table on Department_Table.Department_ID=User_Table.Department_ID\n" +
                    "where Role_ID = 3";
       pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
       rs = pst.executeQuery();
       while(rs.next()){
       String add1 = rs.getString("Department_Name");
       DoctorDep.addItem(add1);
       }
   }catch(Exception e){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
   }finally {
       try {
           rs.close();
           pst.close();
       }catch(Exception e){

       }
   }
```

}

so whenever I click the JComboBox of Department name it will show only the Department name that have a doctors

and also for the Patient Name

```
private void ViewDoctorPatientsBox(){
   try{
       String sql = "Select * from Patient_Records";
       pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
       rs = pst.executeQuery();
       while(rs.next()){
       String add1 = rs.getString("First_Name");
       String add2 = rs.getString("MI");
       String add3 = rs.getString("Last_Name");
       DoctorPatient.addItem(add1+" "+add2+" "+add3);
       }
   }catch(Exception e){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
   }finally {
       try {
           rs.close();
           pst.close();
       }catch(Exception e){

       }
   }
}
```

and in Patient Name I insert the Fname,MI,Lname like so showed in the code above
same with the Doctor Names it only show when I select their Departments like so

```
try{
        String sql = "Select * from User_Table\n" +
                     "inner join Department_Table on User_Table.Department_ID=Department_Table.Department_ID\n" +
                     "where Department_Name = ? AND Availability = 1";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, (String)DoctorDep.getSelectedItem());
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        DoctorNames.removeAllItems();
        DoctorNames.addItem("Select");
        while(rs.next()){
            String add1 = rs.getString("First_Name");
            String add2 = rs.getString("MI");
            String add3 = rs.getString("Last_Name");
            DoctorNames.addItem(add1+" "+add2+" "+add3);
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }finally {
       try {
           rs.close();
           pst.close();
       }catch(Exception e){

       }
   }
```

after I select all I want to select I need to save it to Appointment_Table that only their Doc_ID,Dep_ID,Patient_ID but the JComboBox have the name what syntax should I do?

Answer (score 0):

> that only their Doc_ID,Dep_ID,Patient_ID but the JComboBox have the name what syntax should I do?

Your combo box needs to store two pieces of data:

1. the ID
2. the name.

So you need to create a custom object to store in the combo box and then you need to only display the name in the combo box.

There are two approaches to displaying the name:

1. Create a custom renderer. This is the better approach but is a little more involved. See [Combo Box With Custom Renderer](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/combo-box-with-custom-renderer/) for an example of this approach.
2. Override the toString() method of your custom object to simply return the name. The default renderer for the combo box will invoke the toString() method of the object. See [Combo Box With Hidden Data](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/combo-box-with-hidden-data/) for more information on this approach.

Comment: @Sieccc, I did teach you. Did you read the two links? Unless you ask a specific question I can't guess what you don't understand. Start with the second suggestion as it is the easiest to understand and you can download the test code to test it yourself.

Comment: Sorry about that sir I don't know where to start bcuz im a beginner and I cannot understand the code sorry about that sir..

Comment: What do you mean you don't know where to start. Did you not download the `Item.java` and `ItemTest.java` code? It is a complete example all you have to do is compile. Once again. I have no idea what part of that code you don't understand. How do you learn if you don't try. Being a beginner is no excuse for not test the provided code.